# Show skipped files with ClamAV in Daemon mode

Tags: clamav

By default, ClamAV ignores files lager than 25M. When I try to scan a big file, 700M, I have this output :

```
➜ clamscan file.avi                                                                                                                      
/home/dougui/Videos/file.avi: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8284573
Engine version: 0.102.4
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 700.61 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 13.149 sec (0 m 13 s)
```

The file is marked as correct. When I run the command with `--debug`, I have this log :

```
...
LibClamAV debug: Checking realpath of file.avi
LibClamAV debug: in cli_magic_scandesc (reclevel: 0/16)
LibClamAV debug: cli_updatelimits: scansize exceeded (initial: 104857600, consumed: 0, needed: 734642176)
LibClamAV debug: cli_updatelimits: filesize exceeded (allowed: 26214400, needed: 734642176)
LibClamAV debug: emax_reached: marked parents as non cacheable
LibClamAV debug: cli_magic_scandesc: returning 0  at line 3314 (no post, no cache)
/home/dougui/Videos/file.avi: OK
LibClamAV debug: Cleaning up phishcheck
LibClamAV debug: Freeing phishcheck struct
LibClamAV debug: Phishcheck cleaned up
```

It seems that scansize and filesize are exceeded. There is also a difference between "Data scanned" and "Data read" in summary. I found the option `--alert-exceeds-max` to display when a find is skipped

The problem is I don't find the same option with `clamdscan`. I tried to change the config and checked in log file but didn't found anything.

How can I see which files are skipped in Deamon mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `AlertExceedsMax` in `clamd.conf` fixed my issue. All information is in `man clamd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude these files with `--exclude=/tmpfile`, or use the `-l logfile` if the error are messing with something like Cronic, in my case. The just monitor the logfile with `$(tail "$clamlog" | grep Infected | cut -d" " -f3) != 0`